# CSS is not working on other browsers except IE

Tags: css, stylesheet

I am using this CSS for one `td` but it's not working for other browsers except IE.

```
.tStyle
{
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    background-color: #d2c297;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;

}

<td style="width: 20%; vertical-align: top; display:inline; overflow:auto;" class="tStyle">Example</td>
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Could you show us the code where the `.css` is being set?

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working? And why are you combining inline styling with a CSS class? Why not put everything in the class?

Comment: @ledbutter By 'not working', I assume he means that the styles aren't being applied - And maybe he wants just that control to be outfitted with those custom styles?

Comment: @NewAmbition you are probably right, but I'd rather the OP make that clear. And if it is custom styling just for that element, why not create a separate class for it?

Comment: <td style="width: 20%; vertical-align: top; display:inline; overflow:auto;" class="tStyle"> here only I am applying tstyle class.. . display:inline need to move to css?

Comment: @Vandana Show us the code where you are putting the `.css` file into the page. Such as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">`..

Comment: <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/StyleSheet.css" />

Comment: Don't use the `~`, try the stylesheet without the `~`

Comment: @Vandana Show the entire `<head>...</head>` code please.

Comment: Since you don't want to show us any more code, I'm going to go ahead and guess that your td isn't inside a table. Any takers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try making td inline style display:inline to display:inline-block. And better to have all of your inline css in the class tStyle.

Comment: But... This doesn't explain why only IE is showing the styles..?

Comment: Yes display:inline is creating problem for other browsers if I am removing this from td tag its working fine only thing is that its not showing border whereas in IE its showing . And display:inline-block also not working

Comment: Only border width is added. Can update border-color or as a whole border:2px solid #000;. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZcxZF/1/